# F# type error with one level of indentation, not with another

Tags: syntax, f#

I'm going through the [Hopac](https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac/blob/master/Docs/Programming.md#the-hopac-programming-model) documentation, and I came across this bizarre type error:

```
let create x = Job.delay <| fun () ->
    let c = {reqCh = Ch (); replyCh = Ch ()}
    Job.iterateServer x <| fun x ->
        c.reqCh >>= function
          | Get -> c.replyCh *<- x >>-. x
          | Put x -> Job.result x
    >>-. c

Scrapers.SC.fsx(48,10): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    ''a'    
but given a
    'Cell<'a>'    
The types ''a' and 'Cell<'a>' cannot be unified.
```

`c` is a `Cell<'a>`. This code compiles just fine with the code from the page:

```
let create x = Job.delay <| fun () ->
  let c = {reqCh = Ch (); replyCh = Ch ()}
  Job.iterateServer x <| fun x ->
        c.reqCh >>= function
          | Get -> c.replyCh *<- x >>-. x
          | Put x -> Job.result x
  >>-. c
```

The only difference between these two is the depth of the first indent -- 2 as opposed to 4.

Normally, when there's a problem with indentation, I get a "Possibly incorrect indentation" warning -- not a type error. So it must be *really* confused.

I've been using F# for ten years now, and I still don't understand the indentation rules.

What am I missing?

Comment: "What am I missing?" A thumbs-up vote on https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/470, which is a suggestion to fix the currently-confusing rules. :-)

Comment: @rmunn Done and done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `>>-.` operator is 4 characters, so you need more indentation for it to not be joined with the expression above.  The rule for operators is meant to make stuff like

```
    expr
 |> f1
 |> f2
```

work, with the operators to the left of the expressions in the pipeline.

Comment: By the way, you can read about this in the language spec, it is the first of the "exceptions to the offsides rule"

Answer (score 1):

I see one other indentation difference in that code besides the "2 spaces or 4 spaces" thing, and that is the indentation of `c.reqCh`. In the first example, `c.reqCh` is lined up with `iterateServer`, and in the second, it isn't. I don't fully understand the indentation rules myself (hence why I linked to https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/470 in my comment earlier), but I suspect that the fact that `c.reqCh` is lined up with `iterateServer` is somehow causing the F# parser to misinterpret what it is. (I don't see how, though).

What happens if you take the first example, and add a single space in front of the `c.reqCh` line and the next two lines? In other words, if you change it to look like this?

```
let create x = Job.delay <| fun () ->
    let c = {reqCh = Ch (); replyCh = Ch ()}
    Job.iterateServer x <| fun x ->
         c.reqCh >>= function
           | Get -> c.replyCh *<- x >>-. x
           | Put x -> Job.result x
    >>-. c
```

Now that `c.reqCh` has been indented *past* the start of `iterateServer`, but everything else is identical to the 4-space indentation example, does that make the error go away? If so, then that's the actual difference between the two examples. (Although I still can't explain *why* that indentation was necessary).

I also wonder what would happen if you changed the use of `<|` in `iterateServer` to use parentheses instead, e.g.:

```
let create x = Job.delay <| fun () ->
    let c = {reqCh = Ch (); replyCh = Ch ()}
    Job.iterateServer x (fun x ->
        c.reqCh >>= function
          | Get -> c.replyCh *<- x >>-. x
          | Put x -> Job.result x
    ) >>-. c
```

Does that also make the type error disappear? If so, then we also need to look at the precedence of `<|` to figure out the cause of the error.

Comment: Ah. @Brian's explanation looks like it's correct. It's the `>>-.` operator, not the `iterateServer`, that's causing the indentation issue. Therefore, my last example (with parentheses) should also work, since the closing parenthesis is on the same line as the `>>-.` and therefore it's unambiguous which part of the code is the left operand of the `>>-.` operator.